# Setting a mysql session variable in Pentaho

Tags: mysql, variables, session, pentaho

I have a mysql view that requires several session variables to be set before querying it.
I have tried many ways to set that session variable but have been unable to.

Neither setting it in database connections, with xactions nor executing a set @variable:=value in the sql just before the query has worked for me.

The reason why I need that is because of using this workaround for a view with group by:
http://www.percona.com/blog/2010/05/19/a-workaround-for-the-performance-problems-of-temptable-views/

Do you know how can I set a session variable everytime I open a connection in Pentaho? I need that for CDE and Saiku

Thanks!

Comment: In your PDI connection definition, there is an advanced tab that lets you enter custom SQL that's executed every time the connection is made. But if it doesn't let you do it just before the query, I don't know if that will work.

Comment: I think Brian is talking about the Advanced tab on the Datasource Connection dialog: http://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0H0/060/010/030/000#Specify_Advanced_SQL_Preferences

Comment: Thank you, that's one of the things I tried but it's not working. I add set @testvar_a:=1234; to the advanced tab but when I try to use that variable in an sql it returns null. Maybe it's not happening to everyone?